# MySQL2 prevent from Rails migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to run `heroku rake db:seed` for my Rails app in Heroku. It has a lot of queries involve. I got this error message:

```
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: User '222ad0ef2670fe' has exceeded the 'max_questions' resource 
(current value: 3600)
```

What does current value 3600 means? (queries/hours?) and how can I change it to, say, 10,000?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your issue is with heroku you will need to contact their support team.  In order to change the max_questions variable you need to have root access to the db.  See http://www.mkyong.com/mysql/how-to-modify-the-max_questions-resource-value-in-mysql/ for exactly how to do it.

max_questions is the amount of queries an account on the SQL server can make per hour. 
You will also want to check max_updates, max_connections, and max_user_connections to make sure they line up with the expected traffic load for your app. 
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/user-resources.html for more detail

Answer (score 7):

The reason for the error is you have reached max number of queries per hour. In this case you can wait an hour if you're in developer mode or upgrade your plan.

View [the corresponding FAQ](http://www.cleardb.com/developers/help/faq#multi_7)

> I'm getting an error message saying that I have exceeded the
>   'max_questions' resource for my database. What can I do?
>
> The `max_questions` resource is defined by how many queries you may
>   issue to your database in an hour. Our free plans start with 3,600
>   queries per hour and increase to 18,000 upon purchasing a paid plan
>   with us. Larger plans have larger QPH limits. We recommend that you
>   upgrade your database with us to lift this limitation off of your
>   database

.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your db.  I was on Cleardb ignite, perfect for cheapskates, and I would typically max out max_questions after loading a couple thousand rows during a nightly import.  I bumped up to 'punch' ($9.99/month) and haven't experienced the issue since.